# Firebase messaging stops after receiving a push notification while app in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So i am experiencing a strange behavior in firebase messaging. I am sending both [notification] and [data] objects in my firebase messaging FCM call, when the app is in background, i can receive push notification as many as i call the FCM request. but the issue now when i receive the push notification while opening the app, if i clicked the notification i will no longer receive any further push notifications.

NOTE: If i forced stop the then reopened again, i will start receiving notification again.

I tested this issue on several android devices with several android versions and getting the same results.

Btw, i am using `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'`.

UPDATE: here is the code

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;
    String title, Type, Link, AppVersion, discountExpiry, discountValue, status,
            phone, nid;
    PreferencesHelper ph;
    Map data;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
            Looper.prepare();
        }

        ph = new PreferencesHelper(getApplicationContext());

        data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        Intent intentNotifi = new Intent(click_action);
        intentNotifi.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        title = (String) data.get("title");
        Type = (String) data.get("type");
        Link = (String) data.get("link");
        discountExpiry = (String) data.get("discountexpiry");
        discountValue = (String) data.get("discvalue");
        AppVersion = (String) data.get("appversion");
        status = (String) data.get("status");
        phone = (String) data.get("delivery_phone");
        nid = (String) data.get("nid");

        if (Type != null) {
            Intent notificationIntent;
            switch (Type) {
                case "simple_notification":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;

                case "order_status":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderActivity.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;

                case "news":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsFromNotification.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("nidRef", nid);
                    notificationIntent.getBooleanExtra("fromNotification", true);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;

                case "link":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(Link));
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;

                case "deal_notify":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DealsActivity.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;

                case "after_ordering":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderActivity.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;

                case "no_orders":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;

                case "no_signup":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserActivity.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;

                case "user_points":
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PointsActivity.class);
                    notificationIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;
                default:
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    show_notification(title, notificationIntent);
                    break;
            }
        }

        Looper.loop();
    }


    private void show_notification(String title, Intent intent) {
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon()).setContentText(title).
                        setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                        Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
                android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.logo_notification :
                R.drawable.logo_notification;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you handle the push notification

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler i update my question with the code

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message there docs stately clear for normal notification will only be shown if app is in backgroud.

Answer (score 0):

I found what causing the issue. for some reason

```
 if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
            Looper.prepare();
        }
```

and

```
Looper.loop();
```

Shouldn't be in the code and was preventing onMessageReceived to be called again.